# Identify which segue triggered UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have a `UIViewController` accessible from multiple popover segues from a variety of other `UIViewControllers.` I need to execute some code depending on who the sender is, or maybe depending on the segue identifier. I'm wondering if there's a way to get this information in the popover view without using the `prepareForSegue` method in the parent view controller.

I ask because some of my controllers are really simple and built entirely in IB and as a lazy programmer I don't want to create custom classes for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only issue is that u dont want to create custom classes for simple classes, implement `prepareForSegue` and get to know which segue was triggered by checking the segue.identifier.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// segue.identifier will give you which segue was triggered. Using this info you can branch out your logic......
}
```

Comment: So there is NO way to do it without prepareForSegue?

Comment: There may be other ways too, but even if u do come up with some method that will be called, when a segue is performed. So basically you will be trying to replicate some thing similar to what prepareForSegue is already doing for you. :)

Comment: It would have taken you longer to write this question than to create a custom class for your view controller. You can even create one view controller that is reusable and simply puts the segue name into a property.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == "yourseguename" {
            // do your stuff and then decide if you want to perform it
            return true
        }
        return false
    }`